# Kubernetes Installation failing with on premise HAProxy load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

I am currently trying to form a high availability Kubernetes cluster having 4 worker nodes and 3 master in on-premise server. I learned about implementation of high availability cluster by checking its documentation. I have installed HAProxy 1.8.3. 
While deploying kubernetes using kubeadm, installation is failing with error api server timeout.
So, when i checked my telnet connection from master to HAProxy ip on 6443, Connection closed by foreign host.
Can anyone help me on this problem?

Comment: did you advertise correct master IP address? Can you also provide recreation steps?

Comment: Thank you aurelius for the reply. Issue has been fixed it was the problem with the kernel version were not matching.